# Cannot write to file after reading

Tags: c#, file-io

In the following code I get the error "*stream was not writable*":

```
class Class1
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\fFile.txt", 
                              FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                              FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                              FileShare.ReadWrite);

        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
        string t = r.ReadLine();
        r.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(t);

        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);
        w.WriteLine("string");
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
        fs.Close();

    }
}
```

The error occurs at this line `StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);`

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from msdn

`Closes the StreamReader object and the underlying stream, and releases any system resources associated with the reader.`

So the stream you try to write to is invalid you need to reopen the stream and reopen the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
r.Close();
```

There's your problem after you read.  The close() methods close the underlying stream.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to re-open the file since the read closes it:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", 
                        FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                        FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                        FileShare.ReadWrite);
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string t = r.ReadLine();
    r.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}

fs = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", 
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
            FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
            FileShare.ReadWrite);

using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    w.WriteLine("string");
    w.Flush();
    w.Close();
}
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont close the first `StreamWriter`, it will close the underlying stream.
And use using statements as Oscar suggests.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\fFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
    string t = r.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(t);

    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);
    w.WriteLine("string");
    w.Close();
    r.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not close the StreamReader. Just comment the line below and it will work.

```
 r.Close();
```